Moving python enviroments between several windows 11 pcs
I have a virtual enviroment setup in my local work machine. I created it using the standard venv method. I have include, lib, and Scripts. When it was created the pyvenv.cfg was like this :
home = C:\Users\josel.munoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
include-system-site-packages = false
version = 3.11.3
executable = C:\Users\josel.munoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
command = C:\Users\josel.munoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe -m venv C:\git_test\BDSICE_SQLServer\virtual_enviroment`

I want to transfer this file to another pc to activate the virtual enviroment there.
Ok, i unzip the zipped virtual distribution and then run activate and proceed to change pyvenv.cfg to this:
home = C:\git\BDSICE\virtual_enviroment\Scripts 
include-system-site-packages = false version = 3.11.3 
executable =C:\git\BDSICE\virtual_enviroment\Scripts\python 
command = C:\git\BDSICE\virtual_enviroment\Scripts\python.exe -m venv C:\git_test\BDSICE_SQLServer\virtual_enviroment

but when i run python on the other pc i get :
python No Python at '"C:\Users\josel.munoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe

it ignores the python interpreter of the virtualized distribution and tries to call the local python of the other pc. Anyway i can fix it? it seems it’s a symlink not a real exe file
